# Is this proposition true or false? What is the negation of the proposition?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

I have the following proposition $x,y \in \Bbb R, \exists x \exists y(x^2 + y^2 < 2xy)$. Is this proposition true or false? How can get its negation using Morgan's law?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is false since the negation $$\forall_x \forall_y (x^2 +y^2 -2xy =(x-y)^2 \geq 0)$$
is true.

Comment: Thank you kind sir.